# How select value not exists in another column same database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want select records that have GUID and not exists into parentGUID

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIuUm.png)

i tried this code

```
select code, GUID, ParentGUID
from ac00
where NOT EXISTS (select ParentGUID from ac00 where GUID <> ParentGUID)
order by Code asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close but missing aliases.

```
select code,GUID,ParentGUID 
from ac00 t1 
where NOT EXISTS (select * from ac00 t2 
   where t2.GUID = t1.ParentGUID) 
order by Code asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Type Fields GUID,ParentGUID convert to int , int
2-UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on GUID , NONCLUSTERED INDEX on ParentGUID

Write Sql Codes in Answers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1-
ALTER TABLE dbo.tt ALTER COLUMN [ParentGUID] INT
ALTER TABLE dbo.tt ALTER COLUMN [GUID] INT

2-
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX icl ON dbo.tt([GUID])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX inoncl ON dbo.tt([ParentGUID])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in a faster way. Joins are usually done much faster than inner queries

```
select ac1.Code,ac1.GUID,ac1.ParentGUID 
from ac00 ac1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ac00 ac2
ON ac2.Guid = ac1.ParentGuid
WHERE ac2.Code IS NULL
```

Comment: That's untrue, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists

Comment: It seems you are right!

Comment: My knowledge was outdated: "Many years ago, LEFT JOIN was quicker, but that hasn't been the case for a very long time."